# How to remove commits from GIT origin?

Tags: git, github

I have two remotes for one of my git repositories.

```
1. origin
2. new-origin
```

I always used to push my commits to the `new-origin` remote. But today I accidentally pushed my commits to the `origin` remote. So is there any way to revert these commits from the `origin` remote?.

I have searched and tried a lot of ways but am only getting ways to remove pushed commits. I am scared if I remove those commits by `git reset` it might affect my `new-origin` also.

Comment: have you pushed to new-origin also, if not push it there, then use git reset hard that will remove commits from your local repository then push to origin ( you need to do force push )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I revert a Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comment, firstly push commits to new-origin so your new-origin repository will get updated, then reset your local repository by

```
git reset head~<no of commits here start from 0> --hard
```

After resetting, your head will be at your desired commit. Then push it to origin. You need to force push it:

```
git push origin <branch-name> --force
```

Now your origin repo will be at the desired commit, and then you can update your local repository by pulling from new-origin:

```
git pull new-origin <branch-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose your history looks like this:

```
22222 new commit pushed accidentally to new-origin
11111 last commit that should have been on new-origin
00000 older commits
```

then you can:

```
git push --force new-origin 111111:<branchname>
```

NOTE: `--force` is a dangerous option: you are removing commits from new-origin... work may be lost if you don't pay attention